# query solution sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i struggling with query:

```
select bl.REF_CORP_ID as [Dept id] , bl.REF_CORE_BUDGET_ID, rc.Col_1 , bl.SubmittedDate as [Created Date time] , bl.APPROVED_BY , bl.APPROVED_DATETIME , bl.APPROVAL_FROM
from TABLE1 bl right join TABLE2 rc on bl.REF_CORP_ID =rc.ref_corp_id AND bl.REF_CORE_BUDGET_ID =1
group by bl.REF_CORP_ID , REF_CORE_BUDGET_ID , Col_1 , SubmittedDate , APPROVED_BY , APPROVED_DATETIME , APPROVAL_FROM
```

result in following manner:

```
1   1   IT  2013-07-10 19:29:40.700
1   1   IT  2013-07-10 19:29:40.700
2   1   Sales   NULL
2   1   Sales   NULL
4   1   HR  2013-07-10 19:32:21.720
4   1   HR  2013-07-10 19:32:21.720
6   1   management  2013-07-10 20:24:29.890
```

but this is a i want:

```
1   1   IT  2013-07-10 19:29:40.700
2   1   Sales   NULL
4   1   HR  2013-07-10 19:32:21.720
6   1   management  2013-07-10 20:24:29.890
```

i have two table in which i applied inner join but in one table have same record and second table have only department info with dept name

Comment: And may we *see* the query that generates this output? (We might also need to know the contents of the tables that it references too)

Comment: show query, tables structure

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: select  bl.REF_CORP_ID as [Dept id]  ,
      bl.REF_CORE_BUDGET_ID,
      rc.Col_1 ,
      bl.SubmittedDate as [Created Date time] ,
      bl.APPROVED_BY ,
      bl.APPROVED_DATETIME ,
      bl.APPROVAL_FROM 
      from TABLE1 bl
      right join TABLE2 rc
      on bl.REF_CORP_ID  =rc.ref_corp_id  
      AND bl.REF_CORE_BUDGET_ID =1
      group by bl.REF_CORP_ID  ,REF_CORE_BUDGET_ID ,Col_1 ,SubmittedDate ,
      APPROVED_BY ,APPROVED_DATETIME ,
      APPROVAL_FROM

Comment: You've managed to edit your question, yet thought posting your code in the *comments* was a good idea? Please edit again, put your code in, and make sure you use `{}` so that it's formatted nicely.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The *crude* solution to this issue is to add the keyword [`DISTINCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d
```

And this will remove rows which are *exact* duplicates. However, duplicate rows is almost always the sign of a logical error elsewhere in the query - it's better to fix that than to just bodge things with `DISTINCT`.